# Which is the best way to handle data through hadoop for MongoDB as well as MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop map-reduce and developing an application where I am using hadoop java map-reduce.
My map will get XML as an input which contains more than million records to parse.I also want the process to be completed in minimal time span.
The out put I need in MongoDB as well as in main MySQL tables.
What can be the standard way?

- **Store data into MongoDB directly from reducer class and then push to MySQL?**
- **Store data into MySQL tables as well as in MongoDB from reducer?**
- **Store data into MySQL only from reducer and then from MySQL push to MongoDB?**

Any help here will be useful to me.

Comment: I am confused with hadoop java map-reduce....I guess you know mongodb also provides support for map-reduce : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/

Comment: Yes. But I have XML file as an input which is sent to mapper class for computation and validations which are done in java

Comment: but `collection.mapReduce()` method in java expect java script function for mapper and reducer.

Comment: I am not talking about mongo mapreduce. FYI http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html